# Oracle PL SQL function or procedure to identify client's NIC

Tags: oracle, plsql, nic

Is there an oracle pl sql function or procedure to identify the client's network interface card (NIC) name?

Comment: Post what your tring code

Comment: I am able to get the client's ip address using sys_context('userenv', 'Ip_address') function.

My client has multiple NICs and the PL SQL gets randomly any IP address. I have a server database where I have stored an IP address and validate it with the IP address received by the sys_context function.

Also, please let me know if it is possible to get IP Address for a particular NIC by PL SQL method.

Comment: No. IP address is a logical address. The first 6 digits of the MAC address (OUI) identifies the vendor. You can download the database and browse, yes.